# PHP отправка файла не нажимая кнопку

Tags: php, ajax

Приветствую у меня есть вот такая загрузка:

```html
<input type="file" id="userImg" accept=".png,.jpeg, .jpg" name="UserImage">
<button id="upload"></button>
```

Всё отлично работает, но сначала надо загрузить файл, а потом нажать кнопку.

Вот javascript:

```js
$('#upload').on('click', function() {
    var file_data = $('#userImg').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    alert(form_data);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(php_script_response){
            alert(php_script_response);
        }
     });
});
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы как-только загружался файл, сразу же отправлялось на сервер. Как мне это сделать. Пока что вижу только вариант использования callback

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860721/how-to-handle-onchange-event-on-input-type-file-in-jquery

Comment: Работает! Ответите целым вопросом?